# Windows 7: UAC Shield for same setup.exe shows on one computer but not another

Tags: windows-7, uac, setup

Does anyone know why the UAC badge wouldn't show up for a given setup.exe icon on one computer in Windows Explorer, but when the same executable is copied to another computer, it does?  Both machines are running Windows 7.  Both machines have UAC setting set to "Default", and both setup.exe's dim the screen (secure desktop) and ask for permission when the setup.exe is double-clicked.  So this seems to mostly be a cosmetic issue, and not that the program isn't being elevated properly on the machine not showing the UAC badge.

The only difference I can tell is that the machine that DOES show the UAC badge is Win 7 32-bit Professional, whereas the one that does not show it is Win 7 32-bit Enterprise SP1.

Are there any other settings or factors I should check that might account for this difference?

Answer (score 2):

Try clicking on the desktop background and pressing F5 (refresh).  It's probably just a matter that Windows didn't inspect it immediately and show the badge.  I've seen this happen, particularly when the file is copied across the network.